# Network charges between Azure devops and self hosted agents

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is the network traffic between devops and self hosted agent charged? E.g. When I upload build artifacts etc. Usually they explicitly mention network charges, but I wasn't able to find anything regarding this particular scenario.

Comment: Where do you see an explicit mention of network charges? We've been using AzDo for few months already and did not see any charges related to network. I was not able to find any mention as well on their pricing page. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

Comment: @LMGagne sorry if I worded it poorly. What I meant was, when a network is charged for a certain service, they usually mention it explicitly. I wasn't able to find such a claim for AzDo, but I would like to make sure it's not charged

Comment: Please review and approve my answer. From documentation and my experience this is the best I can propose you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft Documentation, Azure DevOps Services has no pricing based on network bandwidth utilization.
Uploading build artifacts and anything else as a matter of fact to Azure is considered as inbound data transfers and is free.

[Azure DevOps Services pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/)

[Azure Bandwidth pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/)

Comment: What about downloading pipeline artifacts on the build agent? That would be considered outbound traffic.

Comment: Artifacts are stored on AzDo (public space) and downloaded to one of your private agents (VMs or containers running in your Azure AD tenant and Azure subscription). This is considered inbound traffic from an Azure standing. AzDo is a service on its own just like AAD or O365. Pricing for AzDo clearly specifies there is no charge for inbound or outbound traffic while Azure charges for outbound traffic only.